# 2 3x3 Logic Puzzles

Tags: pattern

Two logic puzzles. Which option logically fits the question mark, and why?
These puzzles are from a test on 123test.com.

1.
[image: Puzzle Nr 1]

2.
[image: Puzzle Nr 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

> the answer is the most bottom left, see the pattern as two different part, the blue dot and the green dot. So we can see the dark part always rotated CCW for each color and the dot always move diagonally in two steps (read from left to right, top to bottom)

2.

> the answer is the most top left, I think it's just "make a smaller shape and move it diagonally to the right"

Comment: I agree. That makes he most sense to me

Answer (score 2):

1.

> Look at the L-shape as a 'snake'. Then the 'tail' moves to the 'head' each turn when read left to right, top to bottom. The dot changes colour each time, and occupies position 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1 in the current snake. So, **bottom left**.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 :

The answer is the most bottom left .
Observations :
 1. Both L shaped object are moving CCW.
 2. Both dots  change position to opposite sides(While being inside L            shaped object)

For 2 :

Rightmost in top Row.
Observation :
Merge bottom left vertices of all figure into one, also merge all Lines passing through that vertex into one. Expand sides opposite bottom left vertices in all figures until they meet outermost figure.